# Why do I get the error "Error: no such column: main.<tablename>.<columname>" although it exists?

Tags: sqlite

This works:

```
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /path/to/db
2    uni              /path/to/db
```

also this:

```
sqlite> pragma main.table_info(tsv_storage);
0|id|int|0||0
1|seqid|text|0||0
...
```

and this:

```
sqlite> select count(*) from main.tsv_storage;
198159
```

and also the attached database works:

```
sqlite> select * from uni.fasta_storage where uni.fasta_storage.id = 1;
1 MASNTVSAQ...  Q197F8.1 002R_IIV3 Uncharacterized protein 002R  Q197F8
```

but this not:

```
sqlite> select main.tsv_storage.seqid where main.tsv_storage.id=8;
Error: no such column: main.tsv_storage.seqid
```

EDIT:
and I have also problems with this, do I have to join the tables?

```
insert into main.tsv_storage(seqlength) select length(fasta) from 
uni.fasta_storage where uni.fasta_storage.title = main.tsv_storage.seqid;
Error: no such column: main.tsv_storage.seqid
```

It happens for all columns, not only seqid. I think I did everything that is explained here: http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg12.htm

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `INSERT ... SELECT ...`, the `SELECT` part must be valid query.

You cannot access a column like `main.tsv_storage` without having the table in the `FROM` clause:

```
INSERT INTO main.tsv_storage(seqlength)
SELECT length(fasta)
FROM uni.fasta_storage, main.tsv_storage
WHERE uni.fasta_storage.title = main.tsv_storage.seqid;
```

And the entire commands looks suspicious.
Are you sure you don't want to update the values in the `seqlength` column for *existing* records?
In that case, you would use something like this:

```
UPDATE main.tsv_storage
SET seqlength = (SELECT length(fasta)
                 FROM uni.fasta_storage
                 WHERE uni.fasta_storage.title = main.tsv_storage.seqid);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sqlite> select * from main.tsv_storage.seqid where main.tsv_storage.id=8;
```

You have not defined where to look for the selection. You need to tell the query what fields to search within the table, then define which table you are searching. The `select *` portion tells the query to look in all fields within the table. The `from` portion of the query tells the processes what table to look in. And lastly the `where` portion tells the query what to match when looking.

Comment: right...sorry for that, I wanted to show a minimum working/not working example and failed at doing so. I added the more complicated query that is also bugging me.